# Dynamically setting margins for checkbox without using linear layout

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to know how to set the x,y coordinates for a checkbox programmatically.I have created an axml(image attached) and now I want to set the x, y programmatically.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3sPo.png)
How can I achieve this?Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all always put your code in text format and not as an image:

Now setting x and y in Android is actually very easy:

```
   var checkBox = this.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox);
            checkBox.SetX(float_values);
            checkBox.SetY(float_values);
```